# Aligning a button outside html form with the form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the button which is present outside the form in the same line of the form. The form and both buttons should be responsive and properly aligned on reducing the screen size. I am sharing snippet. Please provide some suggestions.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
     <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
              <select id="cato"  class="form-control" >
                <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
                <option>Good</option>
                <option>Bad</option>
              </select>
            </div>      
            <div class="form-group">
               <select id="subo" class="form-control">
                <option disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
                <option>Good</option>
                <option>Bad</option>   
                </select>
            </div>  
              <button type="submit" onclick="resettable()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Reset</button>    
        </form>
            
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Add Product</button>  
    </body>
```

Comment: buttons run i believe a margin in bootstrap if not placed in a group/form, add simply an overwrite to it, (margin-left: 0px!important)

Comment: Why you're not using `<input type="reset">`?
Why you're not using `<input type="submit">`?
Why not place the input inside the form, then use CSS to position it elsewhere on the page?

Comment: @devfieldnotes, yeah that's one of the things I noted in my answer too.

Comment: @devfieldnotes Because that Add Product button is meant to be a submit button for another form ie a popup modal form. The Add Product button has no relation with above form. I just want this above form and Add Product button aligned in a straight line

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some margin in all elements inside the form like the following

```css
div.form-inline * {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="cato" class="form-control">
          <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
          <option>Good</option>
          <option>Bad</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="subo" class="form-control">
          <option disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
          <option>Good</option>
          <option>Bad</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" onclick="resettable()" class="btn btn-primary mt-1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Reset</button>
    </form>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Add Product</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but The add product button is not in the same line of the form and why is that reset button distorted??

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to keep them together, you can consider them "sibling" elements. So you can put them both in a `div` and style that div to get your desired sizing.

Also, I just changed the `m-2` class on your submit button to `mx-0 my-2` to basically give it no margin on x-axis, and the same margin as before on y-axis.

Edit: Updated to fix vertical misalignment on small screen sizes

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group m-0">
        <select id="cato" class="form-control">
          <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
          <option>Good</option>
          <option>Bad</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group m-0">
        <select id="subo" class="form-control">
          <option disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
          <option>Good</option>
          <option>Bad</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" onclick="resettable()" class="btn btn-primary m-0"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Reset</button>
    </form>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-0 my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Add Product</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

*However*, there's some noticeable issues with your form here:

1. Your "reset" button is set to type `submit`, meaning this would submit the form unless you are capturing it and preventing propagation.
2. Your real submit button is outside the form. I'm not sure if that works, and it doesn't seem like good practice even if it does. If all you want is to space out your submit button differently, consider adding `<br>` tags or using bootstrap classes.

Comment: The button outside the submit button is for another form. That too a popup modal form. How can the form along with button be aligned in straight line?

Comment: You can use `<br>` tags after the form groups, or remove the `form-inline` class from the form

Comment: I also added a class of `container` on the div outside. Removing it would make the whole div stick to the left side again, if that's what you want.

Comment: The reset button is getting distorted on reducing the screen size

Comment: Can you explain what "distorted" means?

Comment: I meant that the reset button is not aligned with form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219677/discussion-between-tripathiakshit-and-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

add `d-inline-flex` to the form:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <form class="form-inline d-inline-flex mt-2 ml-2 align-items-start">
    <div class="form-groups">
      <select id="cato" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
        <option>Good</option>
        <option>Bad</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="subo" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
        <option>Good</option>
        <option>Bad</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="resettable()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Reset</button>
  </form>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-top m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Add Product</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the reset button is distorted on reducing screen size

Answer (score 0):

You can add parent to your form. Add `display:inline-block` and `width:fit-content` and the outside button will be aligned with form